# Shock testing equations (oversimplified?)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision, free-fall

I'm designing a shock test tower with a maximum drop height of 1.8m. I'm adding bungee cords to add impulse and reach the intended 150G as it hits the programmer at the bottom.

My question is, is it safe to use impact force upon contact (at tip of programmer) to get the height and bungee tension set up? What else should I be including? We do not have the average K value of the programmer.

G=a’/9.8

F’=ma’

F’=mv/t (**t is 6ms**)

v=sqrt(2 * 9.8 * y)

The above equations are used to get height(y) velocity(v) and Force (F’) that will eventually give me  the "Gees" using "G=a’/9.8".

I'm trying to get a ballpark idea on the G forces that the DUT will experience.

Comment: What object are  you dropping and what surface is it landing on?

Comment: I'm dropping a plastic box with components inside attached to a platform. This is landing on a half sine wave programmer

Comment: What is the material of the half sine wave programmer?  Also note that a picture would help.

Comment: It is an elastomer. Unfortunately the manufacturer is being stingy with the spec sheet beyond telling me that it can provide the 150G/6ms response.